# Filter tweets based on a language using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I was using tweepy to stream and capture tweets regarding celebrities for a project and realised that half the data wasnt in english(i need it to be in english for analysis for now). So is there a way i can filter the streaming based on the language of the tweet or amply a similar filter somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the streaming data doesn't include the ISO language code so I think the only way to do it will be to detect the language directly ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024934/is-there-a-python-library-class-that-can-take-a-piece-of-text-and-determine-the) might help).  Depending on how much data you're streaming you might want to store the data first and then have a second process to detect the language and discard all the ones you don't want.

Comment: The language parameter has been announced on the streaming documentation page, but is not functional yet: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#language